# Programmatically Installing Windows Service from Application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-services

I currently have a windows service that needs to run in the background while a main application I have written handles UI and other tasks. I install and maintain the GUI application using ClickOnce Deployment and would like to find a way to bundle my Windows Service in as well.

They are in separate projects at the moment since I was still learning how to use the Windows Service.

My question is, is it possible given MyService.exe that I install and start MyService.exe  from MyApp.exe? I can assume that I have access to InstallUtil.exe and could write a script to install and run it manually, but I would like a cleaner solution if there is one.

The only resources I've found all seem to assume I want to have the Service install itself, which is not the case.

Comment: In general, this won't work - Windows Services will require higher permissions than ClickOnce will provide...

Comment: @ReedCopsey Ah I guess I never put 2 and 2 together, I've been iterating and installing using Command Prompt as Admin. That makes sense. If you want to add that as an answer I can accept it, or I will just delete the question when I can.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, ClickOnce can't be used to install services.  There is typically a lack of permissions, but also the location is incorrect, etc.  For details, see MSDN on [Choosing Between ClickOnce and Windows Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973805.aspx) for more details.

If you want to install a service, you should do a traditional installation.